# What does module not callable mean?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command that you need a specific Role for, I've tried to write a code piece that tells the user of the command if they don't have the correct role,

however it throws a type error at me on bot start up saying the the 'module' is not callable?

What does 'module not callable' mean?

Here's the code;

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(875786906443599884)
async def sra(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
if not member:
    member = ctx.author
amod = ctx.guild.get_role(848057125283954688)
loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
await member.add_roles(amod)
await member.remove_roles(loa)
await ctx.send("Welcome back! " + str(member))
modReturnEmbed = discord.Embed(
    title='Return Log', description='This staff member has returned from leave! ' + str(member), color=0x000000)
modReturnEmbed.set_footer(text="LeaveManager Bot")
modReturnEmbed.set_author(name='Leave Manager')
botLogChannel = client.get_channel(874959002172268685)
await botLogChannel.send(embed=modReturnEmbed)

@commands.errors
async def missing_role(ctx, error):
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
    await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command!')
```

Comment: When you ask for debugging help. It's useful to have a complete backtrace, and also a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where is the *rest* of the code?

Comment: It means you are trying to call an object which is a module, but modules are not callable

Comment: I've added the rest of the code as asked

Comment: @Booker5677 no, that code would give you a `NameError` because `client` is undefined, assuming the syntax was correct (currently, it wouldn't even compile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however it throws a type error at me on bot start up saying the the 'module' is not callable?
> What does 'module not callable' mean?

You're trying to **call**() a **module** with `commands.errors()`, which refers to a **file** in the library ([this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/errors.py) is `commands.errors`). This means you're essentially doing `file()` which makes no sense. That's what that error means.

What you should be doing is `@function_name.error`, mind that there is no "s" at the end, it's error not error**s**.

```py
@sra.error  # <- @sra, and "error" not "errorS"
async def missing_role(ctx, error):
    ...
```

Example for error handling from the docs: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/errors.py

Comment: Thank, you that helps a lot, especially for future reference

Comment: @Booker5677 If it helped you out then you should accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having:

```py
@commands.errors
async def missing_role(ctx, error):
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
    await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command!')
```

It should be

```py
@sra.error #The name of the function instead of "commands" and error instead of errors
async def missing_role(ctx, error):
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
    await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command!')
```